# Is $k$-rainbow coloring of a hypergraph NP-complete or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, np-complete, hypergraphs

**A hypergraph is $k$-rainbow colorable if there exists a vertex coloring using $k$ colors such that each hyperedge has all the $k$ colors. The problem is also called "polychromatic coloring"
Is $k$-rainbow coloring of a hypergraph is NP-complete or not?**

I looked at some reference papers such as "Hardness of Rainbow Coloring Hypergraphs by Venkatesan Guruswami and Rishi Sakety" and "Strong Inapproximability Results on Balanced Rainbow-Colorable Hypergraphs by Venkatesan Guruswami and Euiwoong Lee". But these are the only reference I found discuss the problem but the authors foucs on generating balance rainbow coloring for K-uniform hypergraph where each color has to appear the same number of times in the hypergraph. 
It has been proved that K-rainbow coloring for planer graph is P for K= 2 and NP complete for K=3,4 according to this reference "Polychromatic Colorings of Plane Graphs".

My question " Is $k$-rainbow coloring of a hypergraph NP-complete or not?" in general for any hypergraph. I think this problem is related to vertex cover problem.

Comment: If it is NP complete for a very special case (planar graphs with K=3) then it is also NP hard in general since the special case is included in the general phrasing of the problem.  It's NP as well since a coloring is a certificate, which means it is NP complete.